# Editing PNG in GIMP: is it possible to remove lines (used as arrows) and extrapolate the now blank squares?

Tags: gimp, png

I'm using GIMP to prepare this PNG file for vectorization in Inkscape. I've noticed that the vectorization process makes removing these lines far more tedious after the vectorization than before. Removing these lines by using the "Select by Color" tool leaves transparent pixels and I'd like to know how I can give these pixels the colour one could expect them to have based on the colours of neighbouring squares. Is there any way to systemically extrapolate these colours?

This is the PNG I'm editing. 
[image]

Comment: You can try with [Heal Selection](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26101/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-blank-old-comic-word-balloons-while-retaining) making the selection very small and use few surrounding pixels only. But it will definitely leave unwanted artifacts.

Answer (score 4):

Removing black lines using the heal selection tool:

[image: removing black lines]

Comment: You should add that this needs a third-party script - IIRC Heal selection also requires the third-party Resynthesizer plug-in and is usually be packaged with it.

Comment: Where do I get this extension from?

Comment: other answers should get the credit, but here's where you can find the plugin https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer