# Cleaning an image without destroying it

Tags: gimp

I looked for a physical map of Jordan and found [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Jordan_Topography.png), which is exactly what I need except for the red lines. How can I remove the red lines?

I tried in GIMP Select->By Color, selected all the red lines and clicked "delete", but then the red lines were replaced by white lines.

Is there a way to replace the red lines with colors similar to their surroundings, such that the image looks smooth?

Comment: For me the *heal selection* tool always worked quite well (and it's quickly applied too). See http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26101/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-blank-old-comic-word-balloons-while-retaining and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/how-can-i-remove-text-from-a-background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *automatic* way, such as you're looking for. At least, not to my knowledge.

You could have a go at it with the clone or healing tool, which can yield ok results.

- Select the healing brush.
- Set it to hardness 025 and size 30.
- ctrl-click next to the line.
- Draw over the line.
- Optional: fix things a bit with blur brush.

[image: remove lines in Gimp with Healing brush]

Although this can yield ok-ish results, it's work intensive and not all that great. But I can't think of a better way, except maybe choose a different image.